# В чем смысловая нагрузка в условии if (1)

Tags: php

Привет всем.

Разбираюсь с чужим кодом на php. В нем есть конструкция вида

```
 if (1)
    {

    }
```

Может подсказать уважаемый ALL в чем смысл делать условие if (1) ?

Comment: То же самое, что и `if (true) {}`, то есть условие всегда истинно.

Comment: Всем спасибо. Разобрался. Извиняюсь за то что слишком мало контекста.  Все дело в continue. Пример.
`<?php<br>
$tmp = array( 'petya' => '312312', 'kate'=>'123123', 'john'=>'NULL', 'robocop'=>'6665555' );
foreach ( $tmp as $key => $value )
  {
      if ( $value == 'NULL ')
        {
            echo $key." has no card";
            continue;
        }
      if (1)
        {
           echo  $key."has card ".$value."\n";
        }
  }
?>`

Comment: может растолкуете тогда, а то мне дак понятнее не стало  при чем тут `continue` :)

Comment: можно это интерпретировать как true

Comment: искренне сочувствую коду, когда вместо `$name => $number` или `$user => $code` пишут `$key => $value`

Comment: @Alex Talker, почитайте про индокод.

Comment: @teran я вдруг осознал, что поторопился и не причем. и вообще получается какой-то бред :/

Comment: @Эдуард  спасибо за комментарий.  Честно говоря не подумал о таком запущенном варианте.

Answer (score 1):

Так бывает, когда в коде остаются следы отладочных правок. Возможно, в этом месте вместо единицы было раньше какое-то условие, но необходимость в нём отпала. 
Посмотрите, если есть возможность, историю правок
    `git log`
или
    `git blame`.

Comment: Спасибо за фидбек. Наверное вы правы.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $tmp = array( 
           'petya' => '312312', 
           'kate'=>'123123', 
           'john'=>'NULL', 
           'robocop'=>'6665555' 
    );
    foreach ( $tmp as $key => $value ) { 
           if ( $value == 'NULL ') { 
                echo $key." has no card"; continue;  
          /* Новая итерация цикла, в следующий if не попадаем.
             Можно убрать continue, и сделать конструкцию if...elseif - первый вариант;
             Можно оставить всё также, но убрать if(1){} - второй вариант,
             так как его присутствие будет не целесообразно.
             Возможно всё так получилось как раз из-за таких изменений*/
           } 
           if (1) { 
                echo $key."has card ".$value."\n"; 
           }
    }
```

Comment: в это варианте можно убрать if(1) и будет тоже самое

Comment: @AlexTalker я ведь как раз для этого комментарий написал, не прочитали?